# How to enumerate sibling nodes in SyntaxTree using SyntaxWalker

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

Is it possible to emunerate sibling of a node in the SyntaxTree?

In the following example how do I get a list of nodes (orange circles) that are siblings of node marked as orange arrow?

```
 If dayW = DayOfWeek.Wednesday Then
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parent of **If** Statement Node is **MultiLineIfStatement** that provides details **If** and **End If** statements and also **MultiLineIfStatement.ElseIfBlocks** provides information about the **Else** and **ElseIf** statements.

Here is my **VisitIfStatement** methed:

```
public override void VisitIfStatement(IfStatementSyntax node)
  {
     base.VisitIfStatement(node);
     var Block = node.Parent as MultiLineIfBlockSyntax;

     Location Location = Block.GetLocation();
     FileLinePositionSpan LinePosition = Location.GetLineSpan();

     int Level = IndentLevel(Block);

     // Process If and EndIf staments Details here

     // Get the list of ElseIf blocks and Else Block 
     SyntaxList<ElseIfBlockSyntax> ElseIfBlocks = Block.ElseIfBlocks;
     ElseBlockSyntax ElseBlock = Block.ElseBlock;

     / Process ElseIf blocks
     for (int i = 0; i <= ElseIfBlocks.Count - 1; i++)
     {
        ElseIfBlockSyntax ElseIfBlock = ElseIfBlocks[i];
        Location = ElseIfBlock.GetLocation();
        LinePosition = Location.GetLineSpan();

        // **Process ElseIf statements here**

     }

     if (ElseBlock != null)
     {
        Location = ElseBlock.GetLocation();
        LinePosition = Location.GetLineSpan();

       // **Process ElseBlock Details here**
     }
  }
```